# Jquery Form - show/hide/stay visible on writing on input area

Tags: jquery, forms, hover, hide, show

I have researched this for about 3 days non-stop and I'm starting to feel real despair.
Also I have to say that I'm quite a newbie with JQuery, I only do small things now and then.
So, here's the thing: I have this search form (in Wordpress). I want it to be hidden at the start. On mouse over menu link, it hides link and displays search form. On mouseleave, it hides search form and displays link again. I've accomplished this, and this is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#toggle-search').hide();
  jQuery(".buscar").mouseenter(function(){
    jQuery('#toggle-search').show('fast');

    return false;
  });   

  jQuery(".inputbuscar").click(function(){
    jQuery('#toggle-search').show('fast');

    return false;
  });   

  jQuery(".buscar").mouseleave(function(){
    jQuery('#toggle-search').hide('fast');

    return false;
  });
});
```

This would be the html

```
<li id="search-jq" class="buscar">
  <a href="#">Buscar</a>
  <div id="toggle-search">
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="" >
      <div class="form-buscar">
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"></label>
        <input type="text" name="s" id="s" class="inputbuscar" onclick="this.value='';" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="" class="lupa"/>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Css is not really relevant, I'm not applying any display:none.

What I can't do is to make the form still visible if someone is writing and moves the mouse out of the area (i.e, form stay visible while writing (onclick?), despite the mouse being somewhere else, but get form to dissappear if they never clicked in the form). I'm out of perspective now and I don't know if this is really simple or just not possible to do. 
Any hints are really welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Ben Alman's code snippet - https://gist.github.com/450017

```
jQuery.expr[':'].focus = function( elem ) {
  return elem === document.activeElement && ( elem.type || elem.href );
};
```

Then you can do the following:

```
jQuery(".buscar").mouseleave(function(){
  if($('#toggle-search input:focus').length == 0) {
    jQuery('#toggle-search').hide('fast');
  }

  return false;
});
```

**EDIT:** Updated code to use `.data` method to store the corrent search box hover state.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $search = $('#toggle-search');
  var $search_trigger = $(".buscar");
  $search.hide().data('hover', false);

  $search_trigger.mouseenter(function(){
    $search.show('fast').data('hover', true);
  }).mouseleave(function(){
    if($search.find('input:focus').length == 0) {
      $search.hide();
    }
    $search.data('hover', false);
  });

  $(".inputbuscar").click(function(){
    $search.show('fast');

    return false;
  });     

  $search.find("input").focusout(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
      if($search.find('input:focus').length == 0 && $search.data('hover') == false) {
        $search.hide('fast');
      }    
    }, 10);
  });
});
```

Comment: the ":focus" selector is part of jQuery since v1.6, see http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/

Comment: @marc.d - Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't realise it had been included.

Comment: Thank you! This works in Safari and Chrome, but in firefox the form stays after hovering...¿?

Comment: @Kit - please try the updated code. I've taken the libery of rewriting it somewhat. The search box should now stay visible even after the mouse is no longer hovering over it. Additionally, the search box will now hide if the input box and the input button don't have focus and and the mouse is not hovering over the search box.

Comment: @Kit - Here is a jsfiddle.net page for you to try it out on http://jsfiddle.net/5ecNN/

Comment: @devmatt this works absolutely fine in every browser :D - Thank you so much. I have so much to learn. If I can help you with some WP or CSS or anything I might know that you don't please tell me! Thanks again :))

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("#searchform :input").focus(function(){
    $("#toggle-search").show();
});
```

You may also want to look at toogle() to clean up your code a bit: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Thanks Matthew, but this is not working either, the form does show on hover and stays there after that. I placed your code after jQuery('#toggle-search').show('fast');return false;
    });                                Also why would be toggle better than show? :) Thanks again!

Comment: Try it for a single input and see what happens. Toggle would allow you to switch between two states instead of setting them individually.